# I can't view any detailed log for Postfix under Centos

Tags: postfix

I've enabled the -v option on master.cf; but still my /var/log/maillog is almost empty.
I'm having a problem i have my hard times debugging without any log.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

is your syslogd setup to log stuff to maillog? like following:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ grep ^mail /etc/rsyslog.conf 
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

also make sure it's running

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ sudo service rsyslog status
rsyslogd (pid  1356) is running...
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

Comment: In my CentOs mail log is in /usr/local/psa/var/log/maillog

Comment: ^ Florencio is right. It was there for me, too.

Comment: Where does this dash/hyphen come from?  Is that there by default?  I found this the other day and was convinced that I had been hacked and the hacker put the dash there to turn off my Postfix maillog.  Why is the dash there?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same log problem on CentOS-7 with postfix but also with any logger command like:
'logger System testing my log'

Checking deeper, I found out that Rsyslogd was not listening anymore on /dev/log socket !!!!
This can be checked with 'lsof /dev/log'

I fixed the problem, by forcing /dev/log in /etc/rsyslogd.conf.
-- after `$ModLoad imuxsock`
-- add this next line  `input(type="imuxsock" HostName="localhost" Socket="/dev/log")`

This will force usage of /dev/log, which after my last update was no more the default. This is probably a bug. I have the problem with rsyslog-7.4.7-7.el7_0.x86_64 or

Comment: worked for `rsyslog-8.24.0-41.amzn2.2.1.x86_64`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the default Centos 8 install no longer includes rsyslog. The configuration file (/etc/rsyslog.conf) is there, but not the program.

```
dnf install rsyslog
systemctl start rsyslog
systemctl enable rsyslog
```

worked for me.

Comment: CentOS 7 and 8 log to the systemd journal; rsyslog now copies those logs from the journal to the traditional locations in `/var/log`. It is possible to do many other useful things by  working directly with the journal, so it's worth looking at that first if you have any interesting needs (e.g. a centralized log server, more complex searching, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue with delete maillog file and   restart rsyslog service:

```
cd /var/log/
rm -f maillog
service rsyslog restart 
service postfix restart
```

source: http://forum.centos-webpanel.com/postfix/varlogmaillog-no-data-update-when-mail-incoming-and-outgoing/

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similiar issue after moving from centos 7 to a new RHEL 8 install. Rsyslog was writing to maillog intermittently. Watching journalctl (`journalctl -u postfix -f`) showed that most outgoing emails were not being logged. This meant I was missing records when a customer complained about not receiving a receipt. I tried removing the - before /var/log/maillog in rsyslog.conf but this did not solve the issue.

Since I really need an easy way to locate issues with outgoing email deliveries, I just went ahead and set postfix mail log directly

```
postfix stop
postconf maillog_file=/var/log/maillog
postfix start
```