# Set up the right mx records for postfix/dovecot server

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, postfix, dovecot

I recently set up a postfix/dovecot mail-server on my VPS (OVH), but for some reason I cannot receive e-mail through it. Is anyone able to check my DNS-records and my Postfix/dovecot configuration to see where I have gone wrong.

My domain is jeroened.be and mails are handled by mail.jeroened.be

Thanks in Advance

DNS:

```
mail 0 IN CNAME vps115965.ovh.net.
0 IN MX 10 mail
mail 0 IN A 5.196.227.108
mail 0 IN AAAA 2001:41d0:51:1::1e68
```

Postfix:

```
[jeroen@vps105180 ~]$ sudo postconf -n
alias_database = $alias_maps
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 104857600
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = jeroened.be
myhostname = mail.jeroened.be
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
relay_domains = *
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $mydomain
smtpd_sasl_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-client
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtpd_sasl_security_options
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/tls/certs/mail.jeroened.be.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/tls/private/mail.jeroened.be.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 3
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_aliases
virtual_gid_maps = static:2223
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_domains
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_mailbox
virtual_minimum_uid = 2222
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:2222
```

Dovecot:

```
[jeroen@vps105180 ~]$ sudo doveconf -n
# 2.2.10: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 2.6.32-042stab103.6 x86_64 CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)  simfs
auth_mechanisms = plain login
default_login_user = vmail
disable_plaintext_auth = no
first_valid_gid = 2222
first_valid_uid = 2222
mail_access_groups = vmail
mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n
passdb {
  args = scheme=SHA1 /etc/dovecot/passwd
  driver = passwd-file
}
protocols = imap pop3
service auth {
  unix_listener auth-client {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  user = root
}
service imap-login {
  process_min_avail = 1
  user = vmail
}
ssl_cert = </etc/pki/tls/certs/mail.jeroened.be.crt
ssl_key = </etc/pki/tls/private/mail.jeroened.be.key
userdb {
  args = uid=2222 gid=2222 home=/var/vmail/%d/%n allow_all_users=yes
  driver = static
}
```

Maillog (requested):

```
[jeroen@vps105180 ~]$ sudo tail /var/log/maillog
Feb 20 20:35:00 vps105180 postfix/anvil[16609]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:unknown) at Feb 20 20:31:40
Feb 20 20:35:00 vps105180 postfix/anvil[16609]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Feb 20 20:31:40
Feb 20 20:43:20 vps105180 postfix/qmgr[15505]: CF1A812217D7: from=<[contact e-mai]>, size=71118, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 20 20:43:20 vps105180 postfix/virtual[8454]: CF1A812217D7: to=<[my e-mail]@jeroened.be>, relay=virtual, delay=8895, delays=8895/0.07/0/0.03, dsn=4.2.0, status=deferred (delivery failed to mailbox /var/vmail/jeroened.be/[my e-mail]: cannot open file: Is a directory)
Feb 20 20:48:20 vps105180 postfix/qmgr[15505]: 1620712217DD: from=<[contact e-mai]>, size=40090, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 20 20:48:20 vps105180 postfix/virtual[20307]: 1620712217DD: to=<[my e-mail]@jeroened.be>, relay=virtual, delay=8910, delays=8910/0.12/0/0.03, dsn=4.2.0, status=deferred (delivery failed to mailbox /var/vmail/jeroened.be/[my e-mail]: cannot open file: Is a directory)
Feb 20 20:52:12 vps105180 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<[my e-mail]@jeroened.be>, method=PLAIN, rip=178.50.74.180, lip=5.196.227.108, mpid=27858, TLS, session=<doaCY4oPQwCyMkq0>
Feb 20 20:52:14 vps105180 dovecot: imap([my e-mail]@jeroened.be): Connection closed in=1488 out=116410
Feb 20 20:53:20 vps105180 postfix/qmgr[15505]: A773312217DB: from=<[contact e-mai]>, size=13191, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 20 20:53:20 vps105180 postfix/virtual[29577]: A773312217DB: to=<[my e-mail]@jeroened.be>, relay=virtual, delay=8847, delays=8847/0.08/0/0.03, dsn=4.2.0, status=deferred (delivery failed to mailbox /var/vmail/jeroened.be/[my e-mail]: cannot open file: Is a directory)
```

postqueue (requested):

```
[jeroen@vps105180 ~]$ sudo postqueue -p
7322712217DB*    5258 Sat Feb 21 17:47:02  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

EE85F12217EE*   22948 Sun Feb 22 07:25:21  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

C5E4612217E8*    9562 Sat Feb 21 17:26:28  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

6DD8C12217E0*   46645 Sat Feb 21 17:47:02  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

9D13E12217F1*  110258 Sun Feb 22 11:00:18  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

AE11712217DC*    4827 Sat Feb 21 17:29:47  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

AB97312217C2*    4231 Sat Feb 21 17:14:30  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

C04981221808*   18003 Sat Feb 21 17:36:29  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

CB21B12217F4*   78006 Sun Feb 22 11:30:50  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

64FE012217DE*   35693 Sun Feb 22 14:09:28  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

6F91812217FC*    1293 Sat Feb 21 22:15:37  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

EE39312217F8*   20283 Sun Feb 22 11:43:18  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

EB31712217F5*     483 Sun Feb 22 11:37:11  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

81D0512217BD*   14735 Sun Feb 22 04:55:03  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

BB8CC12217E2*    4372 Sun Feb 22 11:42:22  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

9A2B112217EA*    2038 Sun Feb 22 03:00:38  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

7FF1F12217E9*    5258 Sat Feb 21 17:36:47  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

5DF2C12200E8*    2799 Sat Feb 21 17:36:47  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

C27291221805*    4426 Sun Feb 22 16:51:45  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

D9A5912217F6*    7642 Sun Feb 22 11:43:18  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

6A6851221804*     692 Sun Feb 22 16:32:08  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

481F012217E3*    9015 Sat Feb 21 17:26:44  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

CBD1712217B9* 13467594 Sat Feb 21 15:23:52  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

BF0B612217D7*     817 Sun Feb 22 16:56:37  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

B759212217D2*   11127 Sat Feb 21 16:15:24  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

C43241221807*    4327 Sun Feb 22 17:14:35  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

D6D1C12217E4*    9263 Sat Feb 21 17:26:42  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

42AFC12217D8*   30506 Sat Feb 21 18:27:47  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

7100612217ED*    7985 Sat Feb 21 17:06:06  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

B61F612217D4*     667 Sun Feb 22 16:11:19  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

B774912217EF*    4514 Sat Feb 21 17:36:29  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

9FB0D12217F3*  100585 Sun Feb 22 11:20:23  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

8D43212217FD*   21447 Sun Feb 22 13:55:43  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

8B5B712217E5*    9090 Sat Feb 21 17:26:29  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

ED67312217D6*     692 Sun Feb 22 10:43:58  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

C92EC12217D9*   46759 Sat Feb 21 17:36:47  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

A98A412217EB*     263 Sun Feb 22 15:14:36  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

BCAC512217F0*    1293 Sat Feb 21 22:13:05  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

6B92D12217FE*     870 Sun Feb 22 15:31:10  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

B38EC12217E6*   34492 Sun Feb 22 08:07:15  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

CAEC612217D3*    1003 Sat Feb 21 22:24:21  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

7C7911221806*    4579 Sun Feb 22 16:43:19  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

6D5321221800*    4372 Sun Feb 22 13:55:33  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

788D112217E1*    2857 Sun Feb 22 16:33:19  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

1FDAB12217DD*     646 Sun Feb 22 17:08:17  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

A07DD1221809*    3451 Sat Feb 21 15:34:21  MAILER-DAEMON
                                         [e-mail hidden]

BDADB12217EC*    4241 Sat Feb 21 17:13:57  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]

C10F412217F9*  141397 Sun Feb 22 12:03:38  [e-mail hidden]
                                         [e-mail hidden]
```

Comment: @masegaloeh no errors in maillog. That's the reason why I'm thinking about about wrong MX records

Comment: What problem exactly are you seeing then?  DNS looks fine from here.  One possible problem is that jeroened.be is not in $mydestination - is it in /etc/postfix/vmail_domains instead and if so has that been postmapped?

Comment: Please show us your `mail.log`. We can send emails to your server, but all those get rejected by `mail.jeroened.be`, because the users are unknown. Thus, the MX-setup is fine. The problem (which we cannot reproduce or describe) must lie elsewhere in the configuration of your postfix. Could you post a part of the `vmail_mailbox` to see if there's misconfiguration?

Comment: Hi I've added my maillog. FYI: the server did work a few houres. During this period I've received some e-mails. The server stopped working around 4PM on saturday februari 21. The last mail was received on 3:16 PM. The problems in the maillog are resolved

Comment: @sebix this is a example of contents of vmail_mailbox `vleesinblik@jeroened.be         jeroened.be/vleesinblik/`

Comment: `The last mail was received on 3:16 PM. February 21` --> but there are no mention of this email on your maillog? Did the logging system in your server worked?

Comment: I just found out why there are no maillogs since then. It appears that some genius has placed a `-` in front of the path to the maillog in the rsyslogd.conf. I'll be looking for the recent file and add this to the other log

Comment: No solution on the missing-logs, yet (seems there is something else) However I did find all e-mails sent to me in the deferred folder of postfix.

Comment: Great finding, maybe we can trace the problem without the maillog. What's the output of `postqueue -p`? It will tell you why postfix store email in deferred queue.

Comment: @masegaloeh Here is one line of the 48 items it had. Seems there is no reason. `6B92D12217FE*     870 Sun Feb 22 15:31:10  `[email]
                                         vleesinblik@jeroened.be`

Comment: Added the output of postqueue. I only hide emails. EDIT: as I see now all e-mails are having an asterisk. Does that mean something?

Answer (score 2):

The problem(s) are resolved.

As seen in the comments there was a problem saying that my logs did not work. This was resolved following the the instructions on a question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/380406/i-cant-view-any-detailed-log-for-postfix-under-centos) (it is the not approved answer with CentOS 7 in mind)

After the logs worked again the solution was ony 5 seconds away. The logs were saying following error:

```
Feb 22 18:15:27 vps105180 postfix/virtual[26358]: fatal: main.cf configuration error: virtual_mailbox_limit is smaller than message_size_limit
```

I know I had to change this option because I'm sending some large files sometimes (approx. 20MB) But I didn't change the the other option since I was unaware of this problem. By also changing this option the problem was resolved and my e-mail came right in.

Special thanks to masegaloeh and all others to help me find out.

Answer (score 1):

Since you imply you're not getting any error, I'm wondering if the mailboxes you have set in `/etc/postfix/vmail_mailbox` do not match the `/var/vmail/%d/%n` Dovecot virtual mailbox structure.  For example, I would expect it to contain something like:

```
leesinblik@jeroened.be jeroened.be/leesinblik/
```

In any case, look in the /var/vmail directory and see where the mail you have sent has gone.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing **last slash** when you specified maildir directory in `/etc/postfix/vmail_mailbox`.

Excerpt from [man 5 postconf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_mailbox_maps)

> **virtual_mailbox_maps (default: empty)**
>
> ...
>
> > The virtual(8) delivery agent uses this table to look up the per-recipient mailbox or maildir pathname. **If the lookup result ends in a slash ("/"), maildir-style delivery is carried out, otherwise the path is assumed to specify a UNIX-style mailbox file**. Note that $virtual_mailbox_base is unconditionally prepended to this path.

---

The fact is: postfix doesn't fail when **accepting** email, but it fails when **storing** it. That's why another user reported that they successfully sends an email to your server.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments this problem was resolved during the few houres the mail-server was working. There has been no logs created for the period the mail-server did not send/received e-mails.

Comment: Ah, I failed to see the comment :) thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0):

It seems your configuration is fine, I sent a test mail for you at test@jeroened.be, and this is the reply of your server:

```
Feb 22 14:57:22 iabsis postfix/smtp[12704]: DDAE720052E: to=<test@jeroened.be>, relay=mail.jeroened.be[5.196.227.108]:25, delay=6.5, delays=0.33/0.02/6.1/0.03, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host mail.jeroened.be[5.196.227.108] said: 550 5.1.1 <test@jeroened.be>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

This means you server accept the mail, but the receipient doesn't exist (you don't have "test" account on your server).

Comment: Indeed there is no test-account. What app/service did you use to get this output? Can you try the e-mail vleesinblik@jeroened.be this one does exist and is used for spam mails

Comment: Just sent from my own mail server, sent a test mail to vleesinblik, and your server accepted my mail. Feb 22 15:31:09 iabsis postfix/smtp[12963]: 08CE0200775: to=<vleesinblik@jeroened.be>, relay=mail.jeroened.be[5.196.227.108]:25, delay=0.51, delays=0.31/0.02/0.11/0.07, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 2EB1B1221800